# Why is my VarDumper not working in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I've installed VarDumper using composer require. I've called the dump() function in my controller, this should work right?

```
composer require symfony/var-dumper
```

-

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $messages = Array(
            'x' => 'y',
            'a' => 'b',
            'c' => 'd'
            );

    dump($messages);
}
```

This is the error I get. But why can't I call dump in my controller?

```
Attempted to call function "dump" from namespace "App\Bundle\Controller".
```

Comment: What version is your installation of Symfony? What does your controller declaration look like?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Development-like environments

Whithin a development-like envionment (*development*, *test*, etc), you have to make sure the [DebugBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/debug.html) is enabled in the application kernel:

> The DebugBundle integrates the VarDumper component in Symfony applications. All these options are configured under the debug key in your application configuration.

**Solution**

```
// app/AppKernel.php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### Production-like environments

This is a **bad practice** to dump variables in a production environment but some situations can't fit best practices.

Depending on the environment, there may be multiple declarations of the global function `dump()` (in `pear/XML`, `pear/adobd`, etc). Moreover if you look closely at the new Symfony `dump()` function [declaration](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6856c023e3823acb2d9bf237b8504cb8517a5186/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php#L14), it is created only if it doesn't already exist:

```
if (!function_exists('dump')) {
    /**
     * @author Nicolas Grekas <p@tchwork.com>
     */
    function dump($var)
    {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $var) {
            VarDumper::dump($var);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution**

So the good solution is to directly call `VarDumper::dump()` from the namespace `Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper`. I also suggest to wrap it inside an `exit()` to avoid unexpected behaviours:

```
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

class myClass
{
    function myFunction()
    {
        exit(VarDumper::dump(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: Legend! It worked using the 2nd option you provided. Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Make sure that the **DebugBundle** bundle is enabled in the application's kernel

```
// app/AppKernel.php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
   {
        $bundles = array(
        // ...
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            // ...
       }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when upgrading from 2.3 I was missing that Bundle.

Comment: Actually this answer is the correct one. Chosen answer allows you to make it work, but this one makes using dump() function directly

Answer (score 0):

composer global require symfony/var-dumper

You will see : Changed current directory (GLOBAL_COMPOSER_DIRECTORY)

In your php.ini:
auto_prepend_file = (GLOBAL_COMPOSER_DIRECTORY)/vendor/autoload.php

You can then use dump in all your projects without having to install it

Comment: not really working so far. Do I need to include them in an use statement in my symfony project?

Comment: You have to make sure that the modified php.ini is being used by your php stack.

In command-line: php --ini
In apache: <?php phpinfo();

Answer (score -2):

Try to update your project's dependencies with the command `php composer.phar update`. That command must be run after the `composer require symfony/var-dumper`.

Comment: Not really. ["After adding/changing the requirements, the modified requirements will be installed or updated."](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require)

Comment: @sjagr you're right. Maybe OP is missing the `php` in the initial command?